# Comma usage necessary for this type of omission?

Tags: commas

> ...to represent the oppression of and the violence against women.

I don't think I need commas here, but when I read this I would naturally leave a slight pause after "of" and "against", which is usually indication that something is needed. I considered dashes. Any help is appreciated (and would also love to know a grammatical term this problem would fall under)!

Answer (score 1):

From [Richard Nordquist at ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-gapping-1690885):

> - What Is Gapping?
>
> A construction in which part of a sentence is omitted rather than
> repeated. The missing grammatical unit is called a gap. The term *gapping* was coined by linguist John R. Ross in his
> dissertation, "Constraints on Variables in Syntax" (1967), and
> discussed in his article "Gapping and the Order of Constituents," in
> Progress in Linguistics, edited by M. Bierwisch and K. E. Heidolph
> (Mouton, 1970).

Here, it is the prepositional complement *women* that is not repeated (and the sentence sounds accordingly less clunky):

- ... *to represent the oppression of women and the violence against women.*
- ... *to represent the oppression of and the violence against women.*

As with a parenthetical, various offsetting punctuation, always balanced as 'and the violence against' is medial, is available.

Dashes and ellipses would be ponderous here, and brackets only fitting if a real contrastive emphasis were required.

That leaves a pair of commas, a very reasonable choice here, signalling as you say slight pauses ... and zero punctuation. I think the smooth-flowing style that opting for zero punctuation affords here is the best choice, and it is certainly my choice.